# Finding integers corresponding to a 2's complement hex representation

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm worried i'm not understanding what is being asked in this assignment and i'm hoping someone can provide some guidance.

"Find the decimal integer that corresponds to the following doubleword 2's complement hex representation:
34 D7 CF 5B"

Some things I'm hoping are safe to assume is that:

1. it is going to be 32 bits long
2. It will be positive because the leading power is 3 or in binary 0011

I have two methods with two different answer (both of which may be wrong)

Method 1:
Assume it's positive and go straight to converting from hex to dec

```
3*16^7 + 4*16^6 + ... + B*16^0
```

which yields 886558555

Method 2:

```
Convert it to binary
Flip the values (0 to 1 and 1 to 0)
Add 1
Yielding, in binary 1100 1101 0010 1000 0011 0000 1010 0101
or in dec: -853004123
```

Comment: It would be important to know the endianness. But yeah, method 1 is the correct one, method 2 only works for negative numbers (obviously).

Comment: It's 32 bits assuming a word is 16. That's true for lots of processors, but by no means all. The fact that the sign bit (highest order of the nibble 34) is zero means that two's complement is irrelevant. The number is positive.

Comment: Here 2's complement refers to the interpretation of the bits (and it ends up not really mattering since the top bit is 0). I get the confusion, because it's also the name of an *operation* (which you have shown in "method 2"), but if they had wanted you to use that they would have asked the question differently.

Comment: Thank you all for the assurance. Method 1 it is. I think I was just psyching myself out when I saw "2's complement"

Comment: How is this related to either assembly or the 8086?

Comment: invert and add one is the easiest...but you dont know the endianness so at a minimum you have two answers one for each endianness...

Answer (score 0):

2's complement is a specific method of encoding negative numbers.
In order to make a positive number negative or visa versa you invert all the bits and add 1.
The adding works both ways, so you never subtract.

In 2's complement notation the most significant bit (MSB) tells you if a number is negative or not.
Assuming `34 D7 CF 5B` is a 32-bit number as is common (and not a 30-bit number which is unusual) the MSB is zero and thus the number is positive.

Because the number is positive no conversion is needed and we can just calculate the decimal representation from the hex:

```
34 D7 CF 5B
|| || || |+-> 11 * 16^0 = 11
|| || || +--> 05 * 16^1 = 80
|| || |+----> 15 * 16^2 = 3840 
etc.
```

The result is: ‭886558555‬ as you've calculated already.

It's the inversion that forces the MSB to be set in negative numbers.
2's complement works correct when subtracting 1 from 0 and when adding and subtracting from arbitrary numbers. It only breaks down in case of overflow.

In order to detect this many CPU's have a o`V`erflow flag which is set on a change in the MSB of the operand.

Numbers that are positive in 2's complement are also positive in other notations. It's only the negative numbers that are encoded different in different systems.

Note that your method 2 describes how to flip the sign in 2's complement, but because the number is already positive it does not apply and shouldn't be used.